# Install the "timeout" unix utility via Yum

Tags: unix, timeout, utility

How can I install the "timeout" utility via Yum? I haven't been able to Google it effectively because the word "timeout" doesn't just refer to this Unix program.

Comment: You'll need to state what the utility does and where you have heard about it from (perhaps a link?). There could be any number of utilities by such a generic name. The utility itself may not be in the standard repository for your Linux distribution (you should state what that is too, CentOS?, Fedora?) but if it isn't it is likely that something else that will do the job is. This it probably also a question better suited to SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

[timeout](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html) is part of [coreutils](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/packages/name/coreutils), which should be installed anyway. Maybe the developers of your distribution have stripped away that utility.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. It's CentOS, but it's configured strangely, and it didn't have a lot of things installed that I expected.